# Can you simulate key presses in python without any external libaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that can simulate key presses, mouse presses and mouse movements. I am creating it at school where I have the standard python libraries, but cannot download or install any external libraries. Is there a way to simulate key presses etc. by only using the built in libraries?

Comment: What's your operating system? `xdotool` may work.

Comment: But in practice, even if there's no internet connection, you can still copy the libraries to a USB.